# What is SYSRAC SESSION?

Tags: oracle, rac

In my environment (oracle 19c) I can see several SYSRAC sessions. What is the purpose of this session?

```
SQL> select username,status from gv$session where type <> 'BACKGROUND';

USERNAME                       STATUS
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SYS                            INACTIVE
SYSRAC                         INACTIVE
SYSRAC                         INACTIVE
SYSRAC                         INACTIVE
SYSRAC                         INACTIVE
SOE                            ACTIVE
SYSRAC                         INACTIVE
SOE                            ACTIVE
SOE                            ACTIVE
SYS                            ACTIVE
SOE                            ACTIVE

USERNAME                       STATUS
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SOE                            ACTIVE
SYSRAC                         INACTIVE
SYSRAC                         INACTIVE
```

I need to know because sometimes I use a script to kill all sessions and I dont know if I always need to exclude this session of my script (where username <> 'SYSRAC')

I've already research about it, but I just found about `SYSRAC role` from oracle 12c r2

> The following is a list of new features or enhancements provided with
>   Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2):
>
> New Administrator Role
>
> Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2) provides support for separation
>   of duty for Oracle Database by introducing the SYSRAC role for Oracle
>   Real Application Clusters (Oracle RAC) management. SYSRAC, like SYSDG,
>   SYSBACKUP, and SYSKM, enables you to enforce separation of duty and
>   reduce reliance on the use of SYSDBA on production systems. The SYSRAC
>   role is the default mode and is assigned only the priveleges required
>   for connecting to the database by the clusterware agent on behalf of
>   the Oracle RAC utilities such as srvctl.

Comment: According to the documentation, SYSRAC is used by the Clusterware agent. I wouldn't kill it, or anything else with "SYS" in the name.